# Impossible to connect to a website using HttpClient

Tags: android, http

I have a PHP webpage that insert a line in MySQL. What i want to do, is just to connect my android app on this page (no response from the server).

I try to connect from a service and i've heard I should use a thread to connect but it still doesn't work...

Here is my code :

```
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        try {
                        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8888/everbattery/post_sql.php"); 

                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                        httpclient.execute(request);  

                        }
                        catch (ClientProtocolException E){}
                        catch (IOException E) {}
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
```

Any ideas ? I've spend most of my afternoon on that and i'm going crazy ...

Comment: I think your server is not running on your Android device, right? So you should use the IP of the server (NOT localhost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't go for `localhost` in your app.
Try putting actual IP of the machine the server is running on.

You can get to know it by using ipconfig / ifconfig.

Comment: Oh ... I'm so stupid, i didn't pay attention to that.

Thanks a lot, i'm sure you solved my problem.